# Macro for removing whitespace from the start of a string

Tags: macros

I want a macro that somehow replaces whitespace (spaces, newlines, tabs?) from the start of a string.

Something like

```
mystring.replace(/^\s*/g, "")
```

in JavaScript.

Is that possible?

Comment: the `stringstrings` package has a macro `\removeleadingspaces[mode]{string}`.  Whether this is applicable for you will strongly depend on whether the argument you pass to the macro is pure text or has embedded macros.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes : This is what I have been looking for. Submit it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Expandable, infinite spaces

Removing space tokens at the begin of a string is possible, but a little cumbersome:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\TrSp@X\relax
\let\TrSp@Y\relax
\edef\TrSp@XSpXNil{%
  \TrSp@X\space\TrSp@X
  \noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\TrSp@NIL
}
\long\edef\trim@pre@spaces#1{%
  \noexpand\romannumeral0%
  \noexpand\TrSp@pre@spaces\TrSp@X#1\TrSp@Y\TrSp@XSpXNil
}
\@firstofone{\long\def\TrSp@pre@spaces#1\TrSp@X} %
#2\TrSp@X#3\TrSp@NIL{%
  \csname TrSp@pre#3\endcsname{#1}{#2}%
}
\long\def\TrSp@pre#1#2{%
  \expandafter
  \TrSp@pre@\expandafter\space\@gobble#1%
}
\long\def\TrSp@pre@#1\TrSp@Y{#1}
\long\expandafter\edef\csname TrSp@pre X\endcsname#1#2{%
  \noexpand\TrSp@pre@spaces\TrSp@X#2\TrSp@XSpXNil
}
\def\TrSp@X{X}
\let\TrSp@Y\TrSp@NIL
\let\trimstartspaces\trim@pre@spaces
\newcommand*{\trimstartspacesin}[1]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#1%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\trimstartspaces\expandafter{\foo}%
  }%
}
\makeatother


% create a text with several spaces in a row using a trick:
\newcommand*{\deffoo}[1]{%
  \newcommand*{\foo}{#1#1#1#1a b c }%
}
\deffoo{ }
\let\trimmedfoo\foo
\trimstartspacesin\trimmedfoo

\typeout{[\expandafter\trimstartspaces\expandafter{\foo}]}
\typeout{[\trimmedfoo]}

\begin{document}
[\foo] $\rightarrow$ [\expandafter\trimstartspaces\expandafter{\foo}]
  or [\trimmedfoo]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Expandable, at most one space

Package `trimspaces` already provides `\trim@pre@space` or `\trim@pre@space@in`.

Manually it can be done by

```
\romannumeral-`\.
```

`\romannumeral` applied to negative numbers vanishes and TeX keeps looking for an optional space after the character constant `` `\. ``.

If the text is inside a macro `\foo`, then an optional space can be stripped
at the beginning by:

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\foo\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral-\expandafter`\expandafter\.\foo
}%
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\foo}{ a b c }
\expandafter\def\expandafter\trimmedfoo\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral-\expandafter`\expandafter\.\foo
}%
\typeout{[\meaning\trimmedfoo]}

\begin{document}
[\foo] $\rightarrow$ [\trimmedfoo]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Usually removing one optional space is enough, because it is not too easy
entering more than one space in a row (TeX collapses them to one space during tokenizing).

### Non-expandable, infinite spaces

`\@ifnextchar` removes spaces before testing the "next" character. In non expandable contexts it can be used to remove infinite spaces from the begin of the text:

```
\documentclass{article}

% create a text with several spaces in a row using a trick:
\newcommand*{\deffoo}[1]{%
  \newcommand*{\foo}{#1#1#1#1a b c }%
}
\deffoo{ }

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\stripstartspaces}{%
  \expandafter\@ifnextchar\expandafter X\expandafter{\expandafter
  }\expandafter{\expandafter}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
[\foo] $\rightarrow$ [\stripstartspaces\foo]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This strips at most one space token.

Comment: @egreg: I have now added expandable and non-expandable methods for stripping infinite space tokens at the begin.

Comment: I knew this would have triggered some nice code from you. +1!

Comment: `\stripstartspaces` works perfectly for my case. Thanks, accepting.

Answer (score 4):

The `stringstrings` package has a `\removeleadingspaces` macro, which will remove any combination of blanks and hard spaces at the the beginning of the passed text string.  The package is generally intended to operate only upon text strings, and has only a very limited ability (not shown in this answer) to handle arguments containing macros.

By default, the macro will output the result immediately to the screen.  However, if the processed but unprinted result is desired, a `[q]` optional argument will instead put the result in `\thestring` via an `\edef` for later access.  There is also an `[e]` "encoded" mode, which applies if one is trying to process strings containing a limited number of user-predefined macros (but that's for a different question).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
.\removeleadingspaces{abc def}

.\removeleadingspaces{ abc def}

.\removeleadingspaces{  abc def}

.\removeleadingspaces{~abc def}

.\removeleadingspaces{~~abc def}

.\removeleadingspaces{~ ~ abc def}

.\removeleadingspaces{~ ~ abc def}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I originally wanted to accept your answer. However, `\removeleadingspaces` started to make some problems with "forced" breaking words with `\-`, which for unknown reasons started to expand as `......`. `\stripstartspaces` from the other answer works better, I am sorry :)

Comment: @KarelBílek Go with the best answer.  I know that `stringstrings` suffers severe limitations.  I'm glad you found an answer that works for you.